# macro that auto-executes when sheet is opened

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible that my macro (update () ) auto-executes everytime the excel file is opened. The code below doesn't work well. Thanks

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Run "update"

End Sub
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub update()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Sh As String, Cl As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, ncol As Integer
    Dim Row1 As String

    ncol = Range("B1:O1").Columns.Count

    For i = 1 To ncol
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

        With ws
            Row1 = .Cells(1, i).Value

            If Len(Row1) > 0 Then
                Sh = Split(Row1, "'!")(0)
                Cl = Split(Row1, "'!")(1)
                Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sh).Range(Cl)

                'Here you were always refering to cell A2 not moving through the values which was the main problem.
                rng.Value = .Cells(2, i).Value
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is your `Workbook_Open()` sub located? It should be in the code behind `ThisWorkbook` object module. The other code should be in a standard module (ie. `Module1` )

Comment: I agree with @mehow Either `Workbook_Open()` is not in `thisworkbook` or the `Sub Update` is not in a module.

Comment: `The code below doesn't work well. Thanks` What happens exactly? Does the PC blow up or the house catches fire? :D

Comment: @mehow , workbook_open() is saved in the same module as update() and the module is called module1

Comment: Two options. Either change `workbook_open` to `Auto_Open` or move your code `workbook_open` to `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: @SiddharthRout no but my head will... soon... :D coding is so difficult!

Comment: Since @mehow hit the nail on the head, I will let him post a full fledged answer :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout that's OK just leave an upvote for whytheq

Comment: @YasmineNouri consider accepting the answer with the check mark below the votes

Comment: @mehow answer edited accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. Move the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Run "update"

End Sub
```

To here:

[image]

As mentioned by Siddharth there is another way to get a macro to run on the file open event and that is to simply to give it the following signature:

```
Sub Auto_Open
```

Also, personally I'd probably not call a sub-routine just "update" as it is quite close to lots of reserved words - I'd go for something like "updateSomething". This is just personal choice.

Comment: +  1 Bugger You :D I didn't post an answer so that mehow could LOL BTW `Run` is just fine. You might also want to mention about `Auto_Open`

Comment: Run "Update" is fine. It is the same as `Application.Run`

Comment: +1 but seriously the Run "update" and call update is not the cause.

Comment: @mehow: True. It is not

Comment: Sorry couldn't resist it after suggesting it two times in comments that `run "Update"` is just fine :)

Comment: I realise that wasn't the cause - but I thought it was a syntax error as I always use "Call" ...but yes Run "update" seems fine!

Comment: Wish I could just type `LOL` but the comment doesn't accept it :P See Ya guys... Off to gym...