# Opening a closed doc, running its own macro, saving and closing

Tags: vba, excel

I have a main excel file with a macro that lets me build data in archived files.
Currently when my macro runs it adds data to the archived file, saves it and closes it.

```
    CFA.Close savechanges:=True
    myfile = Dir
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Call UserForm_Initialize
```

Inside my archived file it has its own macro that runs the Function Update().  The Function Update() runs when I click a button. The Function Update() takes all the information in the archived file, organizes it and performs certain calculations to update different totals.

Instead of having to go into the file and manually running the Function Update(), I wanted to know if it was possible to add code to the main excel files macro before:

```
    CFA.Close savechanges:=True
```

that would run the Update() function everytime my main excel sheet macro adds data to the archived file.

I tried a few things like:

```
    Application.run Update()
```

But it returns that my function is not defined.

Comment: There are two ways to go about it. `way 1` See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578605/macro-that-auto-executes-when-sheet-is-opened) `way 2` Or you need to fully qualify the code. Something like `Application.run "MyWorkBook.xlsm!MyModule.Update"`

Comment: I tried the with CFA set to my workbook.xlsm, I tried running:    Application.run (CFA.Name & "!module1.Update")  and I get an error message: "Cannot run the macro '01-Jan.xlsm!module1.Update'.  The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.  I checked and made sure all macros are enabled in both files.  But its ok, I just set my archive file to run my Update Function any time a value is added with the:  Private Sub  worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)      Run Update()       End Sub.         Thank you for your help!